# reading data from multiple sockets in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8

I am developing a WP8 application with C# in which I have several sockets from Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket class. I want to read data from the sockets without firing  separate threads for performing blocking read on each of the sockets. However, Socket.Select method is not part of supported APIs in WP8.
So, is there any other ways to mimic the action of Socket.Select with the APIs provided by WP8 or the sole option is to start separate threads for each socket?

Comment: Assuming you are using `ReadAsync` - why would you need a thread per socket?

Comment: Well, if I run one ReadAsync for each socket, then I think I have to await for each one on a separate thread then, right?

Comment: No; the entire point of the `ReadAsync` API is that *it* worries about which (worker) thread it comes back on. You should be `await`ing IO (or using `ContinueWith`) - you should *not* be using `Wait` etc.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I didn't know about it. I will take a look how the way you mentioned works :)